# ¿Es posible declarar un array cuyos componentes sean solo ceros en C++?

Tags: c++, array

¿Es posible declarar un array vacío (es decir, que todos sus componentes sean 0)? Lo haría de forma manual pero debe tener un tamaño de 127.

Comment: No sé C++ y seguro que hay una forma mejor con alguna funcion, se puede hacer con dos for uno para recorrer cada uno de los elementos de array, y otro for, para ese elemento añadirle los 127 ceros, supongo que como cadena.

Comment: Sí. Es posible. A menos que no entendamos qué buscas porque no hay código en tu pregunta.

Comment: Porque han modificado la pregunta, pero ya esta resuelta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sí, es posible:

```
int arreglo[127] = { 0 };
```

De esta forma inicializas todos los elementos del arreglo a **0**.

Comment: Me surge una duda... ¿Cómo sería para inicializar todos los valores con un número distinto de 0? Si sigo tu expresión sustituyendo el `0` por un número cualquiera, únicamente el primer elemento tiene ese valor y el resto del array toma el valor `0`

Answer (score 1):

Con un bucle for puedes insertar automáticamente 0 en cada una de las posiciones del array sin necesidad de colocarlos manualmente:

```
int array[127];

for(int i = 0; i < 127; i++)
{
    array[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, y sabes si hay algun comando o forma de poder declararlo directamente? O esta es la unica forma